# How to check/uncheck a checkbox with javascript in lotus notes

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes

How to check/uncheck a checkbox with javascript in lotus notes?

I´ve tried a lot of different javascript codes but none worked....

the input type checkbox is insidea form called form1..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

View the source for the Web page produced by Domino and determine what the name of your checkbox is.  You're looking for an HTML tag called  with a type="checkbox".  Get the id of that checkbox and use that id to replace the "" part of the code below.

```
document.form1.<YOUR CHECKBOX ID HERE>.checked = true;
```

For example, if the checkbox is named "mycheckbox", the code would be:

```
document.form1.mycheckbox.checked = true;
```

If you need to toggle the checkbox between checked and unchecked, you can use this code, which just sets the checkbox to the opposite state.

```
document.form1.mycheckbox.checked = !document.form1.mycheckbox.checked;
```